# implement change method onclick?

Tags: java, android, google-cardboard, rajawali

Having trouble implementing this method onclick in java on android. The tutors at my school are lost on this as well. This currently runs without error, aside from the fact that a click does not implement `changeImage()`

Do you see any issues with this code? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MyRenderer extends RajawaliCardboardRenderer implements OnClickListener {

    public MyRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void initScene() {
        Log.d("debug1","initScene()");
        Sphere sphere = createPhotoSphereWithTexture(new Texture("photo",R.drawable.panorama));
        getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);
        getCurrentCamera().setPosition(Vector3.ZERO);
        getCurrentCamera().setFieldOfView(75);
    }

    private static Sphere createPhotoSphereWithTexture(ATexture texture) {

        Material material = new Material();
        material.setColor(0);

        try {
            material.addTexture(texture);
        } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50, 64, 32);
        sphere.setScaleX(-1);
        sphere.setMaterial(material);
        return sphere;
    }


    public void changeImage() {
        Log.d("debug1", "" + getCurrentScene().getNumChildren());
        ArrayList<Object3D> objectList = getCurrentScene().getChildrenCopy();
        Material material = objectList.get(0).getMaterial();
        for (ATexture texture : material.getTextureList())
        {
            material.removeTexture(texture);
            texture = null;
        }

        Texture t = new Texture("sphereTexture",R.drawable.newimage);
        t.shouldRecycle(true);
        try {
            material.addTexture(t);
        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    };

    public void onClick(View v) {
        changeImage();
    }
};
```

> change image declaration

```
public abstract class RajawaliCardboardRenderer extends RajawaliRenderer implements CardboardView.StereoRenderer {
 //...
 public void changeImage() {};
 //...
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to call `setOnClickListener()` somewhere? Exactly what is it that the user should be able to click on?

Comment: To be compatible with google cardboard, the function needs to be enabled by a click that occurs anywhere on the screen. I am now looking up setOnClickListener() to see if it's relevant

Comment: I don't know anything about the `RajawaliCardboardRenderer`, but if you're using a `CardboardActivity` here's the [Google Documentation for handling input](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started#handling_inputs).